# XSLT Handle empty cells for CSV if the tag does not exist

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have been trying in this for a long time but I could not find a shortcut solution:
I want to generate a CSV output from XML using XSLT, the CSV contains specific headers, and I want to output the tags related to headers if exists, ***and output "," as a CSV separator for an empty cell when the tag does not exist.***

Example:
XML Input

```
<rootElm>
   <entry>
      <col1>text</col1>
      <col2>text</col2>
      <col3>text</col3>
      <colX>text</colX>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <col1>text</col1>
      <col3>text</col3>
      <colX>text</colX>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <col1>text</col1>
      <col2>text</col2>
      <colX>text</colX>
   </entry>
</rootElm>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="entry">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="col1">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="col1"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text> ,</xsl:text> <!-- comma separator to output empty cell if tag not exist -->
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

        <xsl:when test="col2">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="col2"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text> ,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

        <xsl:when test="col3">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="col3"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text> ,</xsl:text> 
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

The above code works well and generates the wanted result, but I am trying to find a simpler solution such as loop through the wanted header names (col1,col2,col3) and check if the tag with the specified name exists under the "entry" element then apply-templates on it, otherwise print a CSV separator ",". Could this be achievable using XSLT?

CSV output:

```
text,text,text
text,,text //col2 doesn't exist for the second entry
text,text, //col3 doesn't exist for the third entry
```

Comment: Please always specify which XSLT version your processor supports.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Done, xslt-2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/rootElm">
    <xsl:variable name="col" select="distinct-values(entry/*/name())"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="entry">
        <xsl:variable name="entry" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$col">
            <xsl:value-of select="$entry/*[name()=current()]"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="if(position()!=last()) then',' else '&#10;'"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/naZXVEQ/1

---

### Added:

> how can I specify that I want to display only col1, col2, and col3. That I don't want to display colX or any other columns that could be existed.

Simply change the `$col` variable definition to

```
<xsl:variable name="col" select="('col1', 'col2', 'col3')"/>
```

Or even simpler:

```
<xsl:template match="/rootElm">
    <xsl:for-each select="entry">
        <xsl:value-of select="string(col1), string(col2), string(col3)" separator=","/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text> 
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I am looking for, but how can I specify that I want to display only col1, col2, and col3. That I don't want to display colX or any other columns that could be existed.

Comment: See the addition to my post.

Comment: Beware that the ordering of the result of distinct-values() is undefined, according to the W3C spec. In Saxon, `distinct-values()` delivers results in "order of first appearance", which is probably what's wanted here, but other processors may deliver a "random" order.